# IP address range for outbound requests from AWS EC2 in a load-balanced Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Suppose we have an application running on an EC2 instance in a load-balanced Elastic Beanstalk stack. And this application wants to (1) call web services served by external hosts, and/or (2) open secured TN5250 (i.e, 5250 data stream over SSL-secured Telnet) sessions on external hosts.

Is there a way we can give those external hosts a reliable IP address range from which to expect our traffic?

(Cross-posted to the AWS EC2 developer forum.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Amazon EC2 instances are in a **private subnet**, then you will need a **NAT Gateway** in a public subnet to provide them with Internet access. An **Elastic IP address** is associated with the NAT Gateway, which remains static and can be used for whitelisting. All outbound traffic from the instances will come from the NAT Gateway's IP address.

If the Amazon EC2 instances are in a **public subnet** and require a static IP address, they will **each require their own Elastic IP address**. Please note that there are limits on the number of Elastic IP addresses in your account.

Comment: I've passed this thread on to the team working on this application, and they report that the private subnet solution will block us from direct outside ssh access to the EC2 instances. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Also, it is a 'best practice' to secure instances in a private subnet. They could use a Bastion Server (Jump Box) or a VPN connection or Direct Connect connection to access resources in a private subnet. However, you could just as easily keep everything in public subnets and use Security Groups to control access. The one down-side is that each EC2 instance will have its own public IP address. While these addresses will come from a [specific range](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html), it is too wide for whitelisting unless you BYO IPs to AWS.

Comment: "Direct Connect"? Not something I've heard of. All I see in Wikipedia is something about a file sharing protocol. Are you referring to that, or to something different?

Comment: [AWS Direct Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directconnect/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html) involves installing a fiber connection between your location and an AWS region. This is effectively a dedicated VPN, but does _not_ go over the Internet.